# Get icons of all installed apps in android

Tags: android, android-package-managers

I want to get icons of my all installed apps. Can I get that icons using package manager? Is there any function for it? Or any other way to get icons of all installed apps in bitmap?

Thanks!

Comment: Since Android 3.0 you might want to get a bigger launcher icon that you can't get the way you described. If so, perhaps my answer to question below can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600740/getting-app-icon-in-android/16279240#16279240

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
try {
    String pkg = "com.app.my";//your package name
    Drawable icon = getContext().getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(pkg);
    imageView.setImageDrawable(icon);
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException ne) {

}
```

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612233/android-how-to-get-the-icon-of-an-app) for more details.

Comment: Not working with few apps like FB, chrome in android P

Comment: causing outOfMemoryError

Answer (score 10):

Above answers are pretty good.

Your Question is:- **Get icons of all installed apps in android?**
you want list of install apps icon

Here is the code which help you to get install apps list with Application **(icons,packages names)**.

```
**Declare variable in your Activity**

private CustomAppListAdapter customAppListAdapter;
private ArrayList<AppListMain> appListMainArrayList;
private AppListMain appListMain;
```

Just call below function loadApps() in your Activity onCreate()

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_app_list);
    loadApps();
    
}

public void loadApps() {
    try {
        packageManager = getPackageManager();
        appListMainArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfoList = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

        for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resolveInfoList) {
            AppListMain appListMain = new AppListMain();
            appListMain.setAppIcon(resolveInfo.activityInfo.loadIcon(packageManager));
            appListMain.setAppName(resolveInfo.loadLabel(packageManager).toString());
            appListMain.setAppPackage(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName);
            appListMainArrayList.add(appListMain);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

*Here is [Link](https://github.com/ArbazGitHub/Custom-Launcher/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/techno/minilauncher/screens/AppListActivity.java) for reference*

OR

*You can download custom launcher code from My [Github](https://github.com/ArbazGitHub/Custom-Launcher.git) repository*

Answer (score 5):

I find it the easiest way:

```
private List<ResolveInfo> installedApps() {
    final Intent main_intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    main_intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    return package_manager.queryIntentActivities(main_intent, 0);
}
```

Now to get the icons, use this:

```
for(ResolveInfo ri : installedApps()) { 
    // to get drawable icon -->  ri.loadIcon(package_manager)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this way: Make a class called `PackageInformation`:

```
public class PackageInformation {

    private Context mContext;

    public PackageInformation(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    class InfoObject {
        public String appname = "";
        public String pname = "";
        public String versionName = "";
        public int versionCode = 0;
        public Drawable icon;


        public void InfoObjectAggregatePrint() { //not used yet
            Log.v(appname, appname + "\t" + pname + "\t" + versionName + "\t" + versionCode);
        }

    }

    private ArrayList < InfoObject > getPackages() {
        ArrayList < InfoObject > apps = getInstalledApps(false);
        final int max = apps.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            apps.get(i).prettyPrint();
        }
        return apps;
    }

    public ArrayList < InfoObject > getInstalledApps(boolean getSysPackages) {
        ArrayList < InfoObject > res = new ArrayList < InfoObject > ();
        List < PackageInfo > packs = mContext.getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < packs.size(); i++) {
            PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
            if ((!getSysPackages) && (p.versionName == null)) {
                continue;
            }
            InfoObject newInfo = new InfoObject();
            newInfo.appname = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(mContext.getPackageManager()).toString();
            newInfo.pname = p.packageName;
            newInfo.versionName = p.versionName;
            newInfo.versionCode = p.versionCode;
            newInfo.icon = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(mContext.getPackageManager());
            res.add(newInfo);
        }
        return res;
    }

}
```

tuck this away somewhere and now to access the info from your working Activity class do this:

```
PackageInformation androidPackagesInfo = new PackageInformation(this);
ArrayList < InfoObject > appsData = androidPackagesInfo.getInstalledApps(true);

for (InfoObject info: appsData) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, info.appname, 2).show();
    Drawable somedrawable = info.icon;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here below is the code with which you can get the icons of all installed Apps.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            try {
                // try getting the properly colored launcher icons
                LauncherApps launcher = (LauncherApps) this.getSystemService(LAUNCHER_APPS_SERVICE);
                List<LauncherActivityInfo> activityList = launcher.getActivityList(packageName, android.os.Process.myUserHandle());
                drawable = activityList.get(0).getBadgedIcon(0);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }

        if (drawable == null) {

            try {
                getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(packageName);
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```