# Displaying app Icons in list view

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

In my app I want to make a list of app icons using list view. I can get the app icon by using its package name. But I want to display the app icons(no text) on list view so how can I do that. Anyone help me.

This is the code I use to get the application icon.

```
Drawable icon= getPackageManager().loadApplicationIcon("package name");
image view.setDrawable(icon);
```

My question is how we can view the the application icons in list view.

Comment: Can you post some code which you have already tried ?

Comment: @gregn3 I updated my question with code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set app icon like below get using `package name` of any app installed.

```
           Drawable iccon = mContext.getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(
                    pkg);
            icon.setBackground(null);
            icon.setImageDrawable(iccon);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String pkg = "com.app.my";//your package name
Drawable icon = getContext().getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(pkg);
imageView.setImageDrawable(icon);
```

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696121/get-icons-of-all-installed-apps-in-android) for more details.

Comment: I know how to get application icon using package name .I want to know how we can store that icon in arrayList

Comment: Then the question must title like "How to display data in listView" and there are tons of tons tutorials, that explain how to do it

Comment: Yaa I have seen that but I didn't find how to set drawable variable(the variable which contains all my app icons) with list view.Do you know how to do this

Comment: Simple. You need to create ListView, create adapter and create layout of item, then in getView you need to get image of item view via `findViewById` or `getTag` and then call `setImageDrawable` to it.

Comment: Here is a tutorial of how you can work with list views http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: OK thanks a lot for your time and for your help I will go through this link:)