# Get a third party user installed app icon

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new to react-native and I seek your help please. What I am planning to do is to get the app icon associated with an app that the user has installed on his device. 
I did take a look at [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10696164/412628) and realized that I have no way of passing it back to my JS.

Here is what I am doing currently.

```
    private List<String> getNonSystemApps() {
        List<PackageInfo> packages = this.reactContext
            .getPackageManager()
            .getInstalledPackages(0);
        List<String> ret = new ArrayList<>();
        for (final PackageInfo p: packages) {
            if ((p.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 0) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                try {

                    jsonObject.put("name", p.packageName);
                    jsonObject.put("firstInstallTime", p.firstInstallTime);
                    jsonObject.put("installLocation", p.installLocation);
                    jsonObject.put("applicationInfo", p.applicationInfo);
                    jsonObject.put("permissions", getPermissionsByPackageName(p.packageName));
                    Drawable icon = reactContext.getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(p.packageName);

                    ret.add(jsonObject.toString());

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }    
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

Can you please help me out with this ?

Thanks

**Edit**
I managed to get it working, based on Aaron's suggestion, I created another private function just to work with the images. This function will generate the base 64 version of an app's icon.

```
private String getBitmapOfAnAppAsBase64(String packageName) {
    if(packageName.isEmpty() ) return new String("");

    String base64Encoded = "";
    Bitmap bitmap;

    try {
        Drawable appIcon = this.reactContext.getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(packageName);
        if(appIcon instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            bitmap= ((BitmapDrawable)appIcon).getBitmap();
        } else {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(appIcon.getIntrinsicWidth(), appIcon.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        }

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, byteArrayOutputStream);
        byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();
        base64Encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);

    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG,"An error was encounted while getting the package information. The error follows : " + e.toString());
    }


    return  base64Encoded;
}
```

I then use this generated string in my original function, with the following modifications.

**Old Non working code**

```
Drawable icon = reactContext.getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(p.packageName);
```

**New working code**

```
jsonObject.put("icon", getBitmapOfAnAppAsBase64(p.packageName));
```

and then in React-Native - its a piece of pie, since it supports base64 already.

```
"icon" : 'data:image/png;base64,'+installAppObj.icon
```

Huge thanks to Aaron , for guiding me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't already, read through the entire [Android Native Modules](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html) page. It's not that long and addresses several issues you're likely to run into.

Only these types can be sent to your JS code (via a `@ReactMethod`):

```
Boolean -> Bool
Integer -> Number
Double -> Number
Float -> Number
String -> String
Callback -> function
ReadableMap -> Object
ReadableArray -> Array
```

So you effectively have two options:

1. Encode the `Drawable` to one of these types, then decode it on the JavaScript side, or
2. Write the file to disk, and send the path over

I'm not sure what type of `Drawable` the icon is or if there are guarantees. But any of them should be convertible in some way. For example if it's a `Bitmap` you can do a [Bitmap to Base64 String](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9224056/1445366) conversion.

Comment: thanks for the pointer.. Much appreciated. Will mark this as the correct answer because it does not lead me astray :)